# Elastic in docker stack/swarm

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-swarm

I have swarm of two nodes

```
[ra@speechanalytics-test ~]$ docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME                  STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
mlwwmkdlzbv0zlapqe1veq3uq     speechanalytics-preprod   Ready               Active                                  18.09.3
se717p88485s22s715rdir9x2 *   speechanalytics-test      Ready               Active              Leader              18.09.3
```

I am trying to run container with elastic in stack. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  elastic:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.7.0
    environment:
      - cluster.name=single-node
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname==speechanalytics-preprod

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local
```

after start with docker stack

```
docker stack deploy preprod -c docker-compose.yml
```

container crashes in 20 seconds

```
docker service logs preprod_elastic 
...
   | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
   | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: UseAVX=2 is not supported on this CPU, setting it to UseAVX=0
   | [2019-04-03T16:41:30,044][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [unknown] Unable to lock JVM Memory: error=12, reason=Cannot allocate memory
   | [2019-04-03T16:41:30,049][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [unknown] This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out.
   | [2019-04-03T16:41:30,049][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [unknown] Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, soft limit: 16777216, hard limit: 16777216
   | [2019-04-03T16:41:30,050][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [unknown] These can be adjusted by modifying /etc/security/limits.conf, for example:
   | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
   |     # allow user 'elasticsearch' mlockall
   | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: UseAVX=2 is not supported on this CPU, setting it to UseAVX=0
   |     elasticsearch soft memlock unlimited
   | [2019-04-03T16:41:02,949][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [unknown] Unable to lock JVM Memory: error=12, reason=Cannot allocate memory
   |     elasticsearch hard memlock unlimited
   | [2019-04-03T16:41:02,954][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [unknown] This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out.
   | [2019-04-03T16:41:30,050][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [unknown] If you are logged in interactively, you will have to re-login for the new limits to take effect.
   | [2019-04-03T16:41:02,954][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] [unknown] Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, soft limit: 16777216, hard limit: 16777216
preprod
```

on both nodes I have

```
ra@speechanalytics-preprod:~$ sysctl vm.max_map_count
vm.max_map_count = 262144
```

Any ideas how to fix ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The memlock errors you're seeing from Elasticsearch is a common issue not unique to having used Docker, but occurs when Elasticsearch is told to lock its memory, but is unable to do so. You can circumvent the error by *removing* the following environment variable from the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
- bootstrap.memory_lock=true
```

Memlock *may* be used with Docker Swarm Mode, but with some caveats.

Not all options that work with `docker-compose` (Docker Compose) work with `docker stack deploy` (Docker Swarm Mode), and vice versa, despite both sharing the docker-compose YAML syntax. One such option is `ulimits:`, which when used with docker stack deploy, will be ignored with a warning message, like so:

```
Ignoring unsupported options: ulimits
```

My guess is that with your `docker-compose.yml` file, Elasticsearch runs fine with `docker-compose up`, but not with `docker stack deploy`.

With Docker Swarm Mode, by default, the Elasticsearch instance as you have defined will have trouble with memlock. Currently, setting of ulimits for docker swarm services is [not yet](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/88#issuecomment-325805130) officially supported. There are ways to get around the issue, though.

If the host is **Ubuntu**, unlimited memlock can be enabled across the docker service (see [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/issues/152#issuecomment-372903395) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/setting-system-settings.html#systemd)). This can be achieved via the commands:

```sh
echo -e "[Service]\nLimitMEMLOCK=infinity" | SYSTEMD_EDITOR=tee systemctl edit docker.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

However, setting memlock to infinity is not without its drawbacks, as spelt out by Elastic themselves [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/30517#issuecomment-388089466).

Based on my testing, the solution works on Docker 18.06, but not on 18.09. Given the inconsistency and the possibility of Elasticsearch failing to start, the better option would be to *not* use memlock with Elasticsearch when deploying on Swarm. Instead, you can opt for any of the other methods mentioned in [Elasticsearch Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/setup-configuration-memory.html) to achieve similar results.

Comment: ulimit support added to docker service and docker stack deploy: https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/2712